# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, dataframe

```
Department = input("Is there a list you would like to view")


readfile = pd.read_csv('6.csv')
filevalues= readfile.loc[readfile['Customer'].str.contains(Department, na=False), 'June-18\nQty'] 
filevalues = filevalues.fillna(int(0))

int_series = filevalues.values.astype(int) 
calculated_series = int_series.apply(lambda x: filevalues*1.3)


print(filevalues)
```

I am getting this error : `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'`

I have looked through this website and no solutions seems to work. I simply want to multiply the data by 1.3 in this series. Thank you

Comment: `int_series * 1.3`?

Comment: @RafaelC I was attempting to multiply every value in my list by 1.3. I used this method because supposedly it is supposed to convert the series into an int.

Comment: `int_series * 1.3` _does_ multiply every value in the series by 1.3

Comment: @roganjosh Okay, but then do you know the reason for my error?

Comment: The reason is simple: there is no `apply` function in `numpy` arrays. There are, though, in `pandas.Series` objects, which you would have if you did `filevalues.astype(int)` instead of `filevalues.values.astype(int)`

Comment: @RafaelC Okay thank you, it worked! all i did was remove the .value.

Comment: Glad to help @HarisKhaliq :)

Answer (score 1):

There's two issues here.

1. By taking `.values` you actually access the underlying `numpy` array; you no longer have a `pandas.Series`. `numpy` arrays do not have an `apply` method.
2. You are trying to use `apply` for a simple multiplication, which will be orders of magnitude slower than using a vectorized approach.

See below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.arange(1000, dtype=np.float64)})
print(type(df['a']))
# Gives pandas.core.series.Series

print(type(df['a'].values))
# Gives numpy.ndarray

# The vectorized approach
df['a'] = df['a'] * 1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy.ndarray does not have the 'apply' attribute.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html