# How to fix this error :AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, text, preprocessor

How to use the following code in the flask framework, because when I use the following code, always get this error "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'"

```
  message = message.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if len(word) > 4]))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51388050/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-apply)

Comment: What is `df`?  `df['full_text']`?

Comment: Looks like `df` was intended to be a dataframe, but ended up being a dictionary, and `df['full_text']` is a numpy array.

Comment: @3ddavies No. This code is in my model, but I wanted to use this code in the flask framework, but i always get the error AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'. Is it the flask framework cannot use the 'apply' function ?

Comment: @hpaulj data frame, this code was in the model, but i want to convert this code into the flask framework, the following is after convert into flask framework                     
message = message.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([word for word in x.split() if len(word) > 4])), but i always getting error

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Flask framework. You have to focus instead on what is `message`, where did it come from, how was it defined, and what is its **type**. Because as the error indicates, it has no `apply` method.

Comment: You changed the code.  The original looked a lot like it referenced a column of a dataframe.  Now `message` sounds more flask like.  But the name change doesn't help if the actual object is still a numpy array (as indicated by the error).  Whether code runs or not depends on what the object actually is, not on what you intended to be.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `numpy.ndarray`'s do not have an `apply` attribute ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html)).  Pandas `DataFrames` and `Series` objects have `apply`.   With numpy, you can call `np.apply_along_axis` but I think this code probably originally expected `message` to be a pandas `Series`.